# What is the purpose of `pydict_global_version` in dictobject.c?

Tags: cpython

I've been reading CPython internals, and wondered what the `pydict_global_version` counter was doing, and what was it's purpose.

I found the [commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/d43f819caea7) that added it, and references issue #26058 which seems to

I tried reading [PEP 509](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0509/) and couldn't understand the use and purpose of such a **global** private counter.

Could someone smarter than me please explain what is the counters utility?

Comment: Is the question why does it need to be global in particular or why you would want such a counter at all?

Comment: I think I could see its purpose if this was local to the dictionary. But here I have no idea what its purpose is.